# ASP.NET MVC "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tried to make a One-to-Zero-or-One relationship between `User` and `Artist` and chose `ArtistId` to both Primary and Foreign Key but when it comes to inserting data, the database won't let me

Error

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Artists' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

Models

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte RoleId { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
    public class Artist
    {
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }

        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

        public string Bio { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Action in Controller

```
public ActionResult Register(ArtistRegisterViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (viewModel.ConfirmPassword == viewModel.User.Password)
                {
                    var user = new User
                    {
                        Email = viewModel.User.Email,
                        Password = viewModel.User.Password,
                        RegisterDate = DateTime.Now,
                        RoleId = RoleType.Artist
                    };

                    var artist = new Artist
                    {
                        Bio = viewModel.Artist.Bio,
                        ProfilePhoto = viewModel.Artist.ProfilePhoto,
                    };

                    _context.Users.Add(user);
                    _context.Artists.Add(artist);
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                    return Content("New Artist Created");
                }
            }

            return View("Register", viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `ArtistId` so that EF does not create an identity for the PK:

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ArtistId { get; set; }
```

Comment: are you using a pre-existing DB?

Comment: tried to make a new DB but this annotation doesn't appear in a migration so the same DB just regenerated

Comment: You would need to create a new migration to incorporate this change